# How to search for unique users in this dynamodb table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

How does one return a list of unique users from a dynamodb table with the following (simplified) schema? Does it require a GSI? This is for an app with small number of users, and I can think of ways that will work for my needs without creating a GSI (like scanning and filtering on SK, or creating a new item with list of user ids inside). But what is the scalable solution?

```
------------------------------------------------------
| pk      | sk                     | amount | balance  
------------------------------------------------------
| "user1" | "2021-01-01T12:00:00Z" | 7      |
| "user1" | "2021-01-03T12:00:00Z" | 5      |

| "user2" | "2021-01-01T12:00:00Z" | 3      |
| "user2" | "2021-01-03T12:00:00Z" | 2      |

| "user1" | "user1"                |        | 12
| "user2" | "user2"                |        | 5
```

Comment: you need to clarify what a "unique set of users" would be used for in your case -- if there are only a small number of users then storing in set in an item would be best; if there's a lot of users, then again, how are you planning to use this set of total unique users? in most cases you probably want to actually get to some other results based on the unique users.. maybe a count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data model isn't designed to fetch all unique users efficiently.

You certainly *could* use a `scan` operation and filter with your current data model, but that is inefficient.

If you want to fetch all users in a single query, you'll need to get all user information into a single partition.  As you've identified, you could do this with a GSI.  You could also re-organize your data model to accommodate this access pattern.

For example, you mentioned that the application has a small number of users.  If the number of users is small enough, you could create a partition that stores a list of all users (e.g. PK=USERS).  If you could do this under 400kb, that may be a viable solution.

The idiomatic solution is to create a global secondary index.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm still inexperienced with dynamodb, so just to be clear is your PK=USERS idea is essentially to remove the last two user items from the data model listed above, and add an item like this? `{pk: "users", sk: "users", users: [<array of all user objects>]}`

Comment: Exactly.  It's the simplest way to model a one-to-many relationship.  This approach is not without it's drawbacks, but it's super simple and might be enough to fit your use case.  If you are worried about hot partitions, you could keep N copies of the USER partition (e.g PK of USERS#1, USERS#2, ..., USERS#N).  When fetching all users, you could execute a query for PK = USERS#rand(N).